# Link glew.lib as a static library with eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glew

I am a newbie in C++, I made many searches before I ask, I started OpenGL tutorial with C++ , I am using eclipse with GNU cross compiler, I know how to like static libraries with `libXXX.a` format then I want to use `GLEW` library, I have its source code and a precompiled version for windows which is `libglew32.lib`, if I use `make` to compile the source code I get an error which is

`make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:131: recipe for target 'tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o' failed
make: *** [tmp/cygwin/default/shared/glew.o] Error 2`.

if I put the library in the libraries folder and add it to the linker as I do with other libraries I get errors in compiling the project like `undefined reference to 'glewExperimental'` or `Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void glfwMakeContextCurrent(*)'`

**so I have 2 questions:**

1. how can I compile the source code correctly to a static library which I can use in eclipse.
2. can I add `.lib` files to use with eclipse? if yes, how can I do?

Comment: I compiled it using gcc and lined by ar finally I get the libglew.a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled it using `gcc` and lined by `ar` finally I get the `libglew.a`